# my submit form doesn't send in first time but send in second time when submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have a form that I check its values with ajax and if valid then send to another page here is my `index.js`

```
 $("#form").submit(function(event){
    var thisForm = $(this);
    $(".ajaxLogo").show();
    event.preventDefault();

    // do some stuff

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/Check',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
            // ....
            // check some situations that if form is not valid don't send the form
            // ....

            if(result.isOK=='1'){
                alert("I am before this line");
                thisForm.unbind('submit').submit(); // send request to '/'
                alert("I am after that line");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My problem occurs when page loads. The first time I click the submit button I see two `alert`s in browser but nothing happens (form doesn't submit and page doesn't refresh)! However the second time, the form sends and page refreshes. Why?

Also, the second time I don't see the two `alert`s in the browser.

Comment: event.preventDefault();??

Comment: I want to stop submit until validation with ajax is not complete then submit it then I must add `event.preventDefault();` in first is this wrong ?

Comment: JS maybe crashes after the first run and never gets a chance to run again. Depending on you code comments, you forgot closing brackets.

Comment: thanks I forget those in here but brackets is correct in my real code.(I correct this in my question)

Comment: because if I remove `unbind()` then program go in to loop and every time that `thisForm.submit()` call call itself and never form submite

Comment: Why not set the validation request to synchronous and have the success callback return true for the submit event if `isOK == 1` and false if it doesn't? That way no need to `preventdefault` which is probably what is breaking it.

Comment: `async : false` on `$.ajax` object and remove the preventdefault and inner `.submit `

Comment: my registration is currently works in this method and work fine(submit in first click and refresh the page). why must code break ? I am confused :(

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that u keep a global var isok ='' and if all result.isok ="1" than donot do e.preventDefault();. Its not neat way but might solve problem to keep submitting form until ajax validation is done without major code changes.

```
var isok ='';
$("#form").submit(function(event){
var thisForm = $(this);
$(".ajaxLogo").show();
if(isok != '1')
event.preventDefault();

// do some stuff

$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/Check',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(result){
        // ....
        // check some situations that if form is not valid don't send the form
        // ....

        if(result.isOK=='1'){
             isok='1';
            alert("I am before this line");
            thisForm.unbind('submit').submit(); // send request to '/'
            alert("I am after that line");
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: whats are the result value -- are you sure its coming result.isOK=='1' in first click .. if possible provide some jsfiddle demo.